# Wordpress "Add Link to Facebook" plugin

Tags: wordpress

I've been using the Wordpress "Add Link to Facebook" plugin to add links to articles to Facebook. This has been working fine until last night (coinciding with our first scheduled post).

Now, if I go to a published post, I can see "Add link: Facebook error: (#283) Requires extended permission: manage_pages" as a custom post value.

On Facebook, when I go to Settings -> Apps and click the edit icon on the app, it does appear to have the Manage your Pages permission.

I've tried logging out, logging in, deauthorising, reauthorising etc.

Besides the scheduled posts, I have no explanation for why it's suddenly stopped working. Does anybody have any idea what might be going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/april-29-2015-facebook-errors-283-and-200

Facebook forced apps to update to API v2.3 last night. Sounds like something went wrong though, so it's just a matter of waiting for them to fix it...